# What is the recommended pattern for 2 classes that are identical apart from constant names?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, delegates

I have an interface and 2 classes implementing the interface. The only difference between the classes is the constant name, they are being used for the same thing but from different locations. I just want to count how many times the method is called from each different location. Is there a better way of doing this without the repetition or passing in the metric name as a string?

```
public interface OldIdResolver {

    Optional<String> getNewIdFromOldId();

}

public class CustomFieldIdResolver implements OldIdResolver {

    Optional<String> getIdFromLegacyId(String oldId) {

        Optional<Id> newIdOptional = idService.getNewIdFromOldId(oldId);
        if (newIdOptional.isPresent()) {
            statsDClient.incrementCounter("customField.oldIdUsed");
        }
        return newIdOptional;
    }
}

public class SearcherIdResolver implements OldIdResolver {

    Optional<String> getIdFromLegacyId(String oldId) {

        Optional<Id> newIdOptional = idService.getNewIdFromOldId(oldId);
        if (newIdOptional.isPresent()) {
            statsDClient.incrementCounter("searcher.oldIdUsed");
        }
        return newIdOptional;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a single class and make that String a constructor parameter assigned to a field in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily you'd simply make one class and make a constructor:

```
public class AnyMetricIdResolver implements OldResolver {
  private final String metricName;

  public AnyMetricIdResolver(String metricName) {
    this.metricName = metricName;
  }

  Optional<String> getIdFromLegacyId(String oldId) {
     Optional<Id> newIdOptional = idService.getNewIdFromOldId(oldId);
     if (newIdOptional.isPresent()) {
        statsDClient.incrementCounter(metricName);
     }
     return newIdOptional;
  }
}
```

If for some reason that's not good enough (you were rather vague with *'passing the metric name as a string'*), you can make an actual class for each kind of metric string, but still do some code reuse. Keep the IdResolver from above (you may want to make it package private if you must), then start subclassing *that*:

```
public class SearcherIdResolver extends AnyMetricIdResolver {
  public SearcherIdResolver() {
    super("searcher.oldIdUsed");
  }
}
```

You can't make a bunch of classes without actually writing them all, unless you use code generation tools such as Annotation Processors which is certainly possible, but I doubt that's what you're looking for here.

Comment: *"... unless you use code generation tools such as Annotation Processors ..."* - otherwise known as the Gold-plated Toilet Seat design pattern :-)

Comment: What baffles me is that apparently noticed that the methods in the implementation classes do not match the interface method at all; they have a different name and an additional `String` parameter. Further, the `Optional<Id>` can’t be returned when the return type is `Optional<String>`. Besides that, if we assume the methods to match the interface method and the other issue to be solved, this could also be solved by using a lambda expression…